# Auto-accept shared child records with Salesforce to Salesforce does not work

Tags: sharing, master-detail, salesforce2salesforce

I'm trying to share child records (in a master-detail relation of a custom object) to an external org via Salesforce 2 salesforce. So I've set up the connection, published the object on the source org, accepted on the destination org, selected and mapped all fields on the destination org. All good.

Now, whenever I share a record from the source org, it does **not** get auto-accepted on the destination org. I have to manually accept the record, then select a parent and off we go.

What I want is that the child records are automatically accepted in the destination org, and also automatically positioned under the correct parent record.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

So I found the answer. Child records only get auto-accepted on the exact time that

1. Their parent is being switched from 'not being shared' to 'shared'
2. You selected 'also share child records' on the parent record sharing page
3. The child record itself is not in a 'pending/sent...' mode